# Analog of Clang AST in GCC

Tags: gcc, clang, abstract-syntax-tree

Is there analog of Clang AST in GCC?

Sometimes it's usefull to see code as the compiler sees it.
Clang AST options `-ast-view`, `-ast-tree` and `-ast-print` are very helpful here.

I'm interested if there are such options for GCC or some tools to produce AST tree that work with GCC.

Comment: It will also be helpful to have analog of `-fsyntax-only`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dump the (result of the) tree passes by means of `-fdump-tree-all` and the inter-procedural analysis passes by `-fdump-ipa-all`. For a compilation unit `module.c`, this will write dump files `module.c.<num>t.<name>` and `module.c.<num>i.<name>`, respectively.  `<num>` indicated the order in which these passes are run, `<name>` indicates the pass name.

There are also 100s of options controlling dumping for specific passes only, see [GCC Developer Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html#Developer-Options).

These dumps' syntax is mostly C-ish.  After the tree passes there are the machine-dependent RTL passes.  You can dump these with `-fdump-rtl-all` or `-da`.  These dumps are LISP-ish and named `module.c.<num>r.<name>`.
You can also dump the final RTL with `-fdump-final-insns`.

In order to see which RTL is associated to which assembly instructions, you can `-save-temps -dP` and then inspect the assembly file `module.s`.

In the case you are using LTO (`-flto`) the assembly file will only contain lto1 gibberish.  You can add the assembly code by means of `-ffat-lto-objects`.  Notice however that with LTO, this is not the final code as produced by the lto run.  To see that code, use `-save-temps -flto -o program.exe` and the dumps from the LTO run are named `program.exe.ltrans<id>.<num>[tir].<name>`.

Comment: Note that `-fdump-tree-XXX` (and `-fdump-ipa-XXX`) print tree SSA IR which corresponds to LLVM IR (_not_ AST IR).

Comment: I need AST analog.

Comment: `-fdump-tree-original-raw` does the magic

Comment: @trupanka Right, so answer is imprecise.